# Find SMTP server from MS Office 356 Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I'm trying to find my SMTP settings in Outlook for Office 365 pro plus.

But when I go to File -> Account Settings -> Account Settings and click change on my account I don't see my server information:

[image: Outlook Settings 1]

And if I go to More Settings -> Advanced I don't see any server info there either:

[image: More Settings -> Advanced]

This is the version of outlook that I'm using:

[image]

I need to find my SMTP server and what port it's using. How can I get that from this version of outlook?

Comment: Office365 always uses smtp.office365.com and port 587 w/ tls. You will not find this in settings as outlook autonegotiates all this information when it finds out your acct suffix belongs to office365.

Comment: If you are looking for your unique server address (which you dont often need anymore as using the above URL with passing credentials auto uses it), you can send yourself an email, open it in outlook in a new window by double clicking, and then choosing File > Properties. This will show the server value on the first line as xxxxxx.prod.outlook.com

Comment: This is by design, you can't see your SMTP server in Outlook if you are using Exchange Office 365 account. Office 365 account use "smtp.office365.com" server.https://support.office.com/en-us/article/pop-and-imap-email-settings-for-outlook-8361e398-8af4-4e97-b147-6c6c4ac95353

Comment: I see. I was trying to see what SMTP server that outlook uses so I could use it in my python scripts. So it looks like I'm barking up the wrong tree?